# How do I check if multiple letters exist in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

For example in the string "RADIOACTIVE" how do I check if all "R","E" "O" and "A" occur in the string.How should I go about writing the coede

Comment: How about checking each letter at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out which letters are available in your main string. Then check each letter you want whether they are available or not.

```
string S = "RADIOACTIVE";
bool avail[26]={false};
for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++)
  avail[S[i]] = true;


string s = "REOA";
bool All = true;

for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    if(!avail[s[i]])
    {
        All = false;
        break;
    }


if(All)
  cout << "All letters found" << endl;
else
  cout << "All letters not found" << endl;
```